# Forwarding refs by multiple levels [Typescript / React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to follow atomic design principles, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.
I have created three components: Form, ExpandableInput and Input. Input is HTML input wrapper, Expandable input is Input with dropdown and Form is just form. I want to access current input value from Form component so I'm doing ref forwarding by multiple levels. Everything works fine in Form component, but the problem is that I have to use ref.current.value in ExpandableInput component, but I'm getting following error.

> Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance:
> HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement
> | null>'.   Property 'current' does not exist on type '(instance:
> HTMLInputElement | null) => void'.

I don't know how to tell typescript that ref variable in ExpandableInput has type of Ref and is not null. I don't know if ref forwarding by multiple levels is good practice, maybe there is a better way to get input value.

Example code:
**AddForm**

```
const Form = () => {
    // Refs
    const caRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    return (
        <FormTemplate >
            <ExpandableInput
                option={CompetenceAreaOption}
                ref={caRef}

            />
        </FormTemplate>
    );
}

export default AddForm;
```

**ExpandableInput**

```
const ExpandableInput = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, IProps>((
   props,
   ref
): JSX.Element => {

    const pickInputValue = (value: string): void => {
        console.log(ref.current) // Error
        console.log(ref) // Input reference
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <Input
                    ref={ref}
                />
            </div>             
        </div>
    );
})

export default ExpandableInput;
```

**Input**

```
const Input = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, IProps>(({
    props,
    ref
): JSX.Element => {
 
    return (
        <input
            ref={ref}
        />
    );
})


export default Input;
```

Comment: i think you shoud use context instead using ref forwarding

Comment: "I don't know how to tell typescript that ref variable in ExpandableInput has type of Ref and is not null" , so don't pass `null` to `useRef`, also you should make a sandbox your problem

Comment: If you want to access input value, don't use refs, use state, make your input controlled component

Answer (score 0):

There are actually three possible values for the `ref` received by `forwardRef`.

```
type ForwardedRef<T> = ((instance: T | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<T | null> | null;
```

It can be `null`.  It can be what you are expecting, which is a `MutableRefObject` created by `useRef`.  And the third possibility is that it can be a [callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).  (Note: legacy `string` refs are not supported by `forwardRef`).

Any of these three are fine to pass down to the next level.  But if we want to access `ref.current` then we need to make sure that what we have is a `MutableRefObject`.  We do this with a type guard: `if ( ref && "current" in ref)`.  That makes it ok to access `ref.current`.

`ref.current` might be `null` (when the ref hasn't been attached to the DOM yet). So we also need to check that `current` is valid either with an `if` or with the optional chaining operator `?.`

Short version:

```
if ( ref && "current" in ref) {
  ref.current?.focus();
}
```

Long version:

```
// make sure that ref is a MutableRefObject
if (ref && "current" in ref) {
    // input has type HTMLInputElement | null
    const input = ref.current;
    // exlude null current value
    if (input) {
        // now we know that we have an input
        input.focus();
    }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w62BGw)